# Dynamically build a list of parameters to pass to call_user_func (including arrays() as single params)?

Tags: php, events, parameter-passing

How can I dynamically build the array of parameters without knowing before hand how many parameters i need to pass to call_user_func :

As a simple example, suppose the function I was trying to call is as follows :

```
class foo {
   // Param 1 must be boolean,
   // Param 2 must be array(),
   // Param 3 is string
   function bar($param1, $param2, $param3) {
      if($param1 == true) {
         foeach($param2 as $pvalue) {
            echo $param3 . ' - ' . $pvalue;
         }
      }
   }

}
```

And I call this using the class I wrote (inline comments inside the class where I need help)

```
$event = new event('foo');

// Params to Pass
$array  = Array(1,2,3);
$bool   = true;
$string = 'Number: ';

$event::AddParam($bool);
$event::AddParam($array);
$event::AddParam($string);

$event::RaiseEvent('bar');
```

Using the following class I wrote (basically it is to mimic events -- so I believe this is the last thing I need to know to make this 100%),

```
<?php
/**
 *     Copyright (C) {2014}  {MicroVB INC}
 * 
 *         This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *         it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *         the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 *         (at your option) any later version.
 * 
 *     This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *         but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *         MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *         GNU General Public License for more details.
 * 
 *     You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *         along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 *
 * unitrack-invoices
 * event.php
 * 4/13/14 1:11 AM
 *
 */

class event {
    private static $class;
    private static $obj;

    private static $params;

    public static function init($class=false) {
        self::$class = $class;
        if($class) {
            if(class_exists($class)) {
                self:$obj = new $class();
            }
        }
        self::$params = Array();
    }

    public static function AddParam($value) {
        self::$params[] = $value;
    }

    public static function RaiseEvent($function) {
        if(self::$class) {
            if(method_exists(self::$obj, $function)) {
                foreach(self::$params as $param) {
                    // Build each $param into something passable to call_user_func_array
                    // Please note that each item in this array could be an array as well
                }
                call_user_func_array(Array(self::$obj, $function), $paramlist );
                self::$params = Array();
            } else {
                // Method does not exist - throw error;   
            }
        } else {
            if(function_exists($function)) {
                foreach(self::$params as $param) {
                    // Build each $param into something passable to call_user_func_array
                    // Please note that each item in this array could be an array as well
                }
                call_user_func_array(Array(self::$obj, $function), $paramlist );
                self::$params = Array();
            } else {
                // Function does not exist - throw error;   
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Specifically, the problem I am having is here >>

```
        foreach(self::$params as $param) {
            // Build each $param into something passable to call_user_func_array
            // Please note that each item in this array could be an array as well
        }
        call_user_func_array(Array(self::$obj, $function), $paramlist );
```

How can I make the value `$paramlist` -- or whatever is workable here.  Remember, if I pass an array, it would only result in it being `$param1` for `foo::bar()` ...  so I need to be able to break it out dynamically to `$param1`, `$param2`, `$param3` ... etc ... without knowing how many params `foo::bar()` has before hand (aka, I can not statically assign the values beforehand)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution -- here is the working class for anyone interested in creating an event system in PHP. People are more than welcome to update this and add error handling / etc.  I still don't have anything set in here for `__construct` parameter support however if the class being called is specifically for handling events, `__construct` parameters most likely are not needed.

```
<?php
/**
 *     Copyright (C) {2014}  {MicroVB INC}
 * 
 *         This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *         it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *         the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 *         (at your option) any later version.
 * 
 *     This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *         but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *         MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *         GNU General Public License for more details.
 * 
 *     You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *         along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 *
 * unitrack-invoices
 * event.php
 * 4/13/14 1:11 AM
 *
 */

class event {
    private static $class;
    private static $obj;

    private static $params;

    public static function init($class=false) {
        self::$class = $class;
        if($class) {
            if(class_exists($class)) {
                self:$obj = new $class();
            }
        }
        self::$params = Array();
    }

    public static function AddParam($value) {
        self::$params[] = $value;
    }

    public static function RaiseEvent($function) {
        if(self::$class) {
            if(method_exists(self::$obj, $function)) {
                if(count(self::$params) > 0) {
                    call_user_func_array(Array(self::$obj, $function), self::$params );
                } else {
                    call_user_func(Array(self::$obj, $function));
                }
                self::$params = Array();
            } else {
                // Method does not exist - throw error;
            }
        } else {
            if(function_exists($function)) {
                if(count(self::$params) > 0) {
                    call_user_func_array($function, self::$params );
                } else {
                    call_user_func($function);
                }
                self::$params = Array();
            } else {
                // Function does not exist - throw error;
            }
        }

    }

}
```